# Java Realm Results sorting in Java 7?

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-java

```
public class Leaderboard extends RealmObject {
    String score;
}
```

`RealmResults<Leaderboard> leaderboardList = realm.where(Leaderboard.class).distinct("score").findAll();`

The results are `Strings` which are actually just large numbers stored as `String` since Realm does not support `BigInteger`. What I need to do is output those numbers in **numerical order**.

Cannot use `Collections(sort)` since **min sdk is 16**. No luck using StreamSupport lib either. I am currently trying to convert `RealmResults` to a simple array of strings so I can do the sorting on that but I'm having trouble. The following results in a cast error, but even before changes would result in `ldrStrings.get(0)` outputting something like `proxy[((75000))]` which is the real number but surrounded by that text:

> ```
> RealmResults<Leaderboard> leaderboardList =
> realm.where(Leaderboard.class).distinct("score").findAll();
>
>     Leaderboard[] leaderboardArray = (Leaderboard[]) leaderboardList.toArray();
>
>     List<String> ldrStrings = new ArrayList(leaderboardArray.length);
>     for (Object object : leaderboardArray) {
>         ldrStrings.add(object != null ? object.toString() : null);
>     }
>
>     Collections.sort(ldrStrings, new Comparator<String>() {
>         @Override
>         public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
>             BigInteger bi1 = new BigInteger(o1);
>             BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger(o2);
>             return bi1.compareTo(bi2);
>         }
>     });
> ```

Comment: how many objects are we talking about? you'll most likely need to eager-load the `Leaderboard` table for this to work.

Comment: Just one object Score in Leaderboard. Only iterated 5 times (showing top 5 scores)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity: this problem is way over-thought. Here is the solution which takes a RealmResults list, iterates the results into a string array, converts string to BigInteger and sorts them from largest to smallest.

```
     RealmResults<Leaderboard> leaderboardList = realm.where(Leaderboard.class).distinct("score").findAll();
        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < leaderboardList.size(); i++) {
            strings.add(leaderboardList.get(i).getScore());
        }

        Collections.sort(strings, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                BigInteger bi1 = new BigInteger(o1);
                BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger(o2);
                return bi2.compareTo(bi1);
            }
        });
```